# Background Image UITableView changes when scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I set the backgroundImage of my tableView:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Content.png"]];
```

And I set transparent the backGroundColor cells of my table View:

```
SBQCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil){
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];   
    }
```

When I do scroll, the backGroundColor of the Table View changes.

Capture 1 (Without Scroll):

[image: Image1]

Capture 2 (With Scroll):

[image]

Thats the image Im using as background:

[image]

What can I do to skretch the Image background to the full table View? Thanks

Comment: Erm... you notice that the image you're using is darker at the bottom then it is at the top?  That's what's happening.  The image is being repeated...

Comment: You could put a `UIImageView` on the view controller behind the table that holds this image, and then put the table view using transparent tableview background and transparent background for cells, so they just scroll over the static background... stretching the height of your image will drastically change the angle of hte lines you have on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"ContentBg.png"]];
```

More:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}
```

The cells keep transparent when I do scroll and the image for the backGround of the Table View is resized.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Make the background on a view layer behind the TableView, not on the TableView itself and then set a clear background on the UITableView

or...

Set the `tableview.backgroundView` not the `backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the background image as a pattern to the backgroundColor property.

Maybe try this:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Content.png"]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:iv];
```

See the **Apple UITableView** class reference here:

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/backgroundView

Comment: Thanks! I found it: A table view’s background view is automatically resized to match the size of the table view

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
if (cell==nil){
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];   
    }
```

I think you mean:

```
if (cell!=nil) {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];   
    }
```